# pass a $_SESSION value and other input data (select) from jQuery to a saveindb.php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have some select fields and a session id that I need to pass on-the-fly to a php file which will save them into a db.

Let's say I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php

// first I declare the session value
$_SESSION["sess_id"] =  uniqid($prefix = "", $more_entropy = TRUE);
$sess_id = $_SESSION["sess_id"];

// some rows forward, I have my select fields like this one
echo "<select id='num_1' name='num_1' onchange='set_num_1()'>";

?>

<script>
var num_1_val = "";
var session_id = '<?php echo $sess_id();?>';

function set_num_1() {

   num_1_val = document.getElementById('num_1').value;
   /* here I need to put the ajax code to send session_id and num_1_val to save_to_db.php */

   /* I suppose it's some code like follows: */
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_to_db.php",
    data: xxxxxxxx, /* ------------- here is where I fail
    success: function(){
        /* something to do back in case I need */;
    }
   });
}
```

How can I correctly pass session_id and num_1_val to save_to_db.php?

Is there a safer mode to pass $_SESSION["sess_id"] to save_to_db.php without making it visible like now? Because using `var session_id = '<?php echo $sess_id();?>';` I make $sess_id value visible in the page script.

Can you give me a help?
Thanks mates.

Comment: Of course after the select field there are the option ones, within a for loop that takes them from an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var session_id = '<?php echo $sess_id();?>';
```

The best way to pass a session id is using the `Set-Cookie` header [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

You can pass multiple cookies. However PHP does this automatically for you, so i'm unsure what purpose this holds.

Comment: Thank you, but since session data safety is a must, I have to exclude the use cookies for that purpose. And the destination file has no interaction with the browser at all.